# ApiDemos 3.0/3.1 won't build because of unresolved types

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build ApiDemos for API levels 11 (3.0) and 12 (3.1). I've updated to the latest version both tools (revision 11) and platform tools (revision 4). In addition, I have the compatibility package installed.

When I try to build the ApiDemos project I get thousands of errors, of which Eclipse shows 100 of the following:

```
ActionBar cannot be resolved to a type  ActionBarDisplayOptions.java    /ApiDemos3.1/src/com/example/android/apis/app   line 34 Java Problem

ActionMode cannot be resolved to a type Grid3.java  /ApiDemos3.1/src/com/example/android/apis/view  line 133    Java Problem

alertDialogIcon cannot be resolved or is not a field    AlertDialogSamples.java /ApiDemos3.1/src/com/example/android/apis/app   line 82 Java Problem

animator cannot be resolved or is not a field   FragmentHideShow.java   /ApiDemos3.1/src/com/example/android/apis/app   line 55 Java Problem

Animator cannot be resolved to a type   AnimationLoading.java   /ApiDemos3.1/src/com/example/android/apis/animation line 73 Java Problem
```

I need help getting the samples to build properly. Thanks.

Comment: What target did you specify in your project?

Comment: This is actually the answer. See my other comment below to the selected answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that the compatibility jar file only contains support for Fragments and not classes like ActionBar which are only available in API11 and 12. Unless you build with API11 or 12 as your target, you will be unable to use these classes.

Comment: Actually your comment earlier was correct - the target wasn't the right target. By default 1.6 was chosen and once I change to 3.0 (for ApiDemos 3.0) it was OK. 3.1 still fails to compile with 2 errors which I'm not sure aren't actual bugs. But I don't have time to investigate. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for solving this. I wonder why they put a sample like this which I guess hardly anybody is able to get running without encountering this issues. One would expect to just import the sample project and it builds, given the SDK for the preconfigured API level (4 in this case) is installed. Weird.

Answer (score 3):

It is actually the answer for further problems with ApiDemos for API 15.
If someone has a problem running it due to some errors (around 3000 errors in my case) then the answer is editing 'project.properties' file so it says `target=android-15` instead of `8`.

Rebuild/ clean+rebuild your project then.