# Can't import ActionBar in Android App with backwards compatibility

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-actionbar, compatibility

I have an Android application that targets API 17 and has a minimum SDK version of 8. I'm not interested in providing the ActionBar in devices with Android API < 11, but I'd like to use in the devices running Android >= 3.0.

Browsing stackoverflow in order to learn how to do so, I stumbled upon this question: [How to code backward compatible new feature in Android SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558638/how-to-code-backward-compatible-new-feature-in-android-sdk). I wanted to use the implementation provided in its answer, but I can't import android.app.ActionBar. Eclipse would not recognise it.

What could be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976298/apidemos-3-0-3-1-wont-build-because-of-unresolved-types ?

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't choosing the right target.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that your project is referencing the android.jar file for the target, rather than the minimum SDK.

In eclipse, right click project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path, and see which Android version is referenced there.

Comment: Thanks! In fact I was targeting Android 2.2 instead of 4.2. Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [action bar sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) ?

Comment: I'm working on an app that was only meant for handsets, so it has a whole layout not considering the action bar (since it's minimum SDK version is 8). Now I'm designing a new layout for tablets. That's why I don't need Action Bar support for Android versions earlier than 3.0. 
If I ever decide to unify both layouts (handset version and tablet version) I'll use ActionBarSherlock. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html)

> Beginning with Android 3.0 (API level 11), the action bar appears at
>   the top of an activity's window when the activity uses the system's
>   Holo theme (or one of its descendant themes), which is the default.
>   You may otherwise add the action bar by calling
>   requestFeature(FEATURE_ACTION_BAR) or by declaring it in a custom
>   theme with the windowActionBar property.